# Why XmlAdapter in JAXB is abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, interface, jaxb, abstract-class

I always use interface when there is no common implementation between the subclasses. However, the built-in `XmlAdapter` in JAXB is an abstract class, and **ALL** the methods there are abstract, why it's not made interface instead of abstract class? There should be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlAdapter` defines two abstract methods, and also a default no arg protected constructor.

`Unmarshaller`s and `Marshaller`s creates the instances of `XmlAdapter` using the default constructor (unless an instance is provided with `setAdapter`).

My initial thought was that the reason was ensuring there is always a default no-arg constructor for `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller`, but as you stated, if a subclass of `XmlAdapter` declared an non no-arg constructor, that would make the default constructor of `XmlAdapter` not visible. In fact, an `XmlAdapter` implementation that added a constructor with args, and did'nt provide the no-arg constructor, would cause the Marshall/Unmarshall operation to fail unless instances where provided with `setAdapter` methods.

So, there is not practical reason to use and abstract class instead of an interface *with the current implementation*.

My guess is this was a design decision as using and abstract class is best suited from an evolution perspective. If for example, at some point some kind of common initialization where required in the constructor, it could be implemented on the now empty constructor. Or if a method where required in the `XmlAdapter` to marshall a list of objects, it could be implemented with something like this:

```
public List<ValueType> marshalList(List<BoundType> list) throws Exception {
    List<ValueType> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BoundType b: list) {
        result.add(marshal(b));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And JAXB internal classes could use this method without the need of modifying any of the adapter implementations.

Comment: If the class that will extend XmlAdapter has a non-`no-arg` constructor, wouldn't this make the default no-arg constructor non-visible?

Comment: What I mean is, the subclass of XmlAdapter won't inherit its no arg protected constructor

Comment: You are right. A subclass could add a non no-arg constructor, and that would make no-arg constructor not visible. It still would be called from the non no-arg constructor because of the chaining of constructors, but as it's doesn't nothing It's really not needed. That would make sense if the XmlAdapter no-arg constructor did some initialization, but that is not the case.